# How to install spacy-hunspell on MacOS

Tags: python, pip, spacy, hunspell

When I run `pip3 install hunspell==0.5.0`, it seemingly installs without a hitch.

```
Collecting hunspell==0.5.0
Installing collected packages: hunspell
Successfully installed hunspell-0.5.0
```

Now, once I run `pip3 install spacy-hunspell` it seemingly installs as well.

```
Installing collected packages: spacy-hunspell
Successfully installed spacy-hunspell-0.1.0
```

However, once I open my project and import the package, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genVocab.py", line 5, in <module>
    from spacy_hunspell import spaCyHunSpell
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy_hunspell/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hunspell import HunSpell
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hunspell.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN8Hunspell14add_with_affixERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES7_
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hunspell.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/hunspell.cpython-37m-darwin.so
```

I've tried building `hunspell`, `pyhunspell`, and `spacy-hunspell` each from their source repos with different compiler flags and versions of GCC, but the problem persists.

Any idea how to move forward from here?

Comment: Have you run `brew install hunspell` per the [docs](https://github.com/tokestermw/spacy_hunspell)?

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/380) which appears to point to python3.6, could be an issue with python 3.7 as well

Comment: @C.Nivs `brew install hunspell` also seems to work out ok, reporting: `Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/hunspell/1.6.2_1: 852 files, 1.8MB, built in 58 seconds` after `make` `make check` and `make install` complete successfully.

Comment: I'm going to go with `aspell` -- close enough.